# Loose mirror on the door?

Tags: wood, adhesive

I have a mirror fixed on a door.[image: mirror on a door] [image: loose mirror]
Now the mirrors is loose and the top part has quite large space. So the mirror is no longer well glued and I am wondering it may fall in the future.

My question is how to fix the mirror on the door?
I feel it is hard to deliver glues to the small gap.
It may be too much work to remove the gap and mirror first.  Any suggestion is welcomed !

Comment: glass or plastic mirror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an internal hollow door. That fluff you see between the mirror and door is a part of the MDF exterior sheet.

**TOOLS NEEDED:**
**80 and/or 120 grit sandpaper**, *long spatula*, construction grade adhesive, **clean carpet/blanket**, *heavy weights (gallon full bottle or two)*, hammer, **long nail**, and *a strong helping hand*.

**INSTRUCTIONS:**
*• Hold 80 grit sandpaper on one side of spatula handle’s base, then fold over tip of spatula, back to other side of spatula handle’s base*
**• Insert 80 grit sandpapered spatula into gap and remove as much as fluff possible**
*• If fluff persists, use 120 grit sandpaper this time to remove fluff*
**• Apply construction grade adhesive in between the mirror and door, trying to cover as much surface area as possible**
*• Place mat, blanket, or something soft and clean of debris, if you do not have a carpeted floor*
**• Remove pins from mirror door’s hinges with hammer and long nail**
*• With the aid of a strong helper, carefully place mirror side of door facing down, flat on floor*
**• Place weights onto corner of door**
*• Leave door in this state for recommended duration mentioned on construction adhesive instructions for use*
**• With the aid of a strong helper, place door back and drive pins back in**
*• Congratulations. Job well done!*

Comment: When clamping the glass be sure you have the appropriate safety equipment. Also do not place the clamp directly to the glass but use a piece of wood long enough to cover the area that is getting clamped, a few inches wide would be about right.

Answer (score 5):

A high quality construction adhesive should do the trick. The gap looks wide enough that you should be able to get the nozzle of the adhesive tube between the door and the mirror. Apply the adhesive around the perimeter of the door behind the mirror, Clamp the mirror to the door until the adhesive is set.

Be sure to wipe off any excess adhesive that seeps out before it dries.

As @Michael Karas suggests, be sure to check that the gap can be easily closed flush with the door before gluing and clamping. If the door has warped or something has gotten behind the mirror, clamping could risk cracking the mirror.

Comment: Make sure to advise a careful examination of the mirror and door to see if it is easy to close the gap without a lot of just hand pressure. It would not be wise to just squirt in the construction adhesive into the gap and then force the gap closed with a strong clamp, Glass itself is not particularly flexible and if the wood part of that door has taken a hard warp the clamping could very well end up cracking the mirror.